# How to attach two types of files into a intent using the setType

Tags: android, file

I'm attaching a different type of files (Audio, Video and Images).
But I want to do it one by one and in each kind of file (audio, video and images) select different the types of format.

Example:
- for Audios >> mp3 and wma
- for images >> png and jpg
- for videos >> mp4 and mov

How I can do it? I'm setting the type in a intent like "intent.setType("video/*");"

Thx in advance.